# Which free chess (learning) programme would you recommend?

Tags: learning, software

I sadly do not have the time for a paid engagement regarding chess, yet I would like to use a good (learning) programme in my spare time.

I used an old programme from my grandfather, but it doesn't work on the new OS anymore. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is your current level of chess?

Comment: This question should have been closed. Questions which are primarily opinion based or ask for suggestions are not good questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at Lucas Chess.

http://www-lucaschess.rhcloud.com

From its web:

**Play:** The program has 21 engines prepared to play from the start, and with very different levels, from 1300 to 3000 elo.

**Train:**
You have an extensive list of trainings with which to try to improve your chess:

- Training positions
- Play like a grandmaster
- Training mates

**Compete:** In Lucas Chess there are several competitions, and in two of them you can publish the results.

Comment: Is there a linux version of Lucas Chess or is it only for Windows?

Comment: @Dineshkumar I haven't used Lucas Chess for a long time, and being myself a linux user I had taken for granted that there was a linux version, but in the download section only there are *.exe files. You can try to use it under wine, which does the trick many of the times.

Comment: I was about to ask the same thing. I even looked up for any email contact on the website but couldn't find any. I'll try to run it under Wine when I get home. :-)

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion the very best way to learn chess is to play random opponents and learn via your mistakes. I've been playing chess on several iOS apps for a few months, but I've found that playing real people is the best because you can plan your moves and strike when they do not see the plan. Playing a computer is usually too easy, or too hard depending on the settings you choose.
The computer will not make natural mistakes, but rather purposeful mistakes based on the difficulty level. 
As you play against other people, you will get better if you pay attention. You just have to play dozens of games to build an elementary style. With time and practice you'll be able to predict what your opponent is planning and make your moves and plan fit with that in mind. 
I simply use the following app, and play when I have time:
The ads are annoying but I'm not in a race to play so I don't mind....

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/chess-with-friends-free/id295436227?mt=8

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you can try to use a compatibility setting which is a sure feature in the newer version of the windows.
Secondly- I would recommend using http://www.chess.com if you have access to internet in your spare time.
Also you can try using Chessmaster, a popular software.
For trial version you can go to the following link: http://chessmaster-10th-edition.en.softonic.com/

Comment: Stolen software is not the same as free.

Comment: According to my knowledge torrent provides genuine software, and even if you are write I have listed other answers also

Comment: @PeteBecker, please read the answer

Comment: The name of the site ought to tell you something: "The Pirate Bay" isn't there to sell legitimate software. Especially when UbiSoft, the owner of the Chessmaster series, offers patches and add-ons for the 10th edition but **doesn't** offer a free download of the software itself.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but maybe you should delete the piratebay line. I do have a chess.com account, but I am searching for a program, which does not require an internet connection.

Comment: I deleted the link to thepiratebay. Please don't promote piracy.

Answer (score -1):

I still love shredder chess, it's powerful and I'm sure I read somewhere that Carlsen recommended it.

Comment: But is it free, though?

Comment: The OP wants a **free chess software**, can you verify that there is a free version of Shredder?

Answer (score -1):

ChessHero at http://innokuo.altervista.org/chesshero.html is a free tool, for windows only, which allows you to load a PGN or FEN to test your play.  (So you don't random positions, i suggest a FEN such at Reinfeld 1001.)  ChessTempo is adjusted to your level but is only available online.  There are many free videos online or downloadable.  There are many free chess playing programs you can download.

To be more specific, I would need to know which OS you have, your current level, how much time you want to invect, etc.